# jQuery: Delete string in the textarea once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delete a string from a textarea using jQuery once.

However, every time i run my code, I get the following error and nothing gets deleted from the textarea at all:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <span data-price="5.99" data-name="Stamina" class="pricetag">Stamina</span>
```

To explain this better, I created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bt7dvq8x/1/)

If you click on the texts under the textarea, it should remove the string in the textarea but nothing happens.

This is my current code:

```
$(document).one('click', '.pricetag',function(){

 $("#Finalized").contains('<span data-price="5.99" data-name="Stamina" class="pricetag">Stamina</span>').remove();   

});
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

EDIT:

I tried this and still doesn't delete anything from the textarea:

```
$(document).one('click', '.pricetag',function(){

// $("#Finalized").contains('<span data-price="5.99" data-name="Stamina" class="pricetag">Stamina</span>').remove();


    $('#Finalized').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html().indexOf('<span data-price="5.99" data-name="Stamina" class="pricetag">Stamina</span>') != -1;
}).remove();

});
```

Comment: You need to do string manipulation for this.As text inside textarea is not html elements it is plain text.

Comment: you're using .contains incorrectly - see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

Comment: you want to remove only '<span data-price="5.99" data-name="Stamina" class="pricetag">Stamina</span>' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're trying to achieve? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt7dvq8x/2/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.pricetag',function(){
   $("#Finalized").text($("#Finalized").text().replace('<span data-price="5.99" data-name="Stamina" class="pricetag">Stamina</span>',''));
});
```

if you want to replace all the occurrences, you can use regex for that, e.g. like  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: This works absolutely fine. but how do I delete the strings that have been appended to the textarea using jQuery?

Comment: what's problem there? I can append and remove without problems, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt7dvq8x/3/)

Comment: That is perfect and I am doing the exact same thing in my code but I still get the same error and nothing gets deleted!! this is very strange.

Comment: you have one there instead of on (for attaching click event)

Comment: I changed that to on as well and I still get the same error without anything being deleted/replaced!

Comment: and which code are you trying now? If the one I've posted works, why don't you use that? Is there something specific you want to achieve or I missed something?

Comment: yes, i'm using your code. your code work fine in jsfiddle but when i put in my page, it stops working.

Comment: and what is the error reported by browser? do you have jquery properly linked in BEFORE your custom code?

Comment: I have no idea what the issue was but now it started working on its own using your code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help